# Google Analytics Data API (GA4)

Tags: php, google-analytics-4

I used Google Analytics Data API (GA4) API for php.

The events to Google Analytics 4 has sent like this:

```
gtag('event', 'asc_cta_interaction', {
    'page_type': 'widget',
    'element_text': 'widget_open_close',
    'event_action_result': 'close',
    'link_url' : '',
    'item_number': '',
    'item_condition' : '',
});
```

So, I want to retrive all events that has element_text parameter equal with "widget_open_close". All events name are asc_cta_interaction, only parameters is changed.

How could I do this?

My php code:

```
$property_id = 'test';
    
$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient([
   'credentials' => 'test' 
]);

        $filterExpression = new FilterExpression([
            'filter' => new Filter([
                'field_name'    => 'eventName',
                'string_filter' => new StringFilter([
                    'value' => 'widget_open_close',
                ]),
            ]),
        ]);

        // Make an API call.
        $response = $client->runReport([
            'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
            'dateRanges' => [
                new DateRange([
                    'start_date' => '2020-03-31',
                    'end_date' => 'today',
                ]),
            ],
            'dimensions' => [
                new Dimension(
                    [
                        'name' => 'eventName',
                    ],
                ),
                new Dimension(
                    [
                        'name' => 'streamId',
                    ],
                ),
            ],
            'metrics' => [
                new Metric(
                    [
                    'name' => 'eventCount',
                    ],
                ),
              
            ],
            'dimensionFilter' => $filterExpression,
        ]);

     
       
        foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) {
            $eventName = $row->getDimensionValues()[0]->getValue();
            $pageType = $row->getDimensionValues()[1]->getValue();

       
            echo "<pre>"; var_dump($row->getDimensionValues()[0], $row->getMetricValues()[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you created the custom dimensions? for example you should have a custom dimension named exactly: element_text

Comment: i tried to edit your question title, but right now there are too many requests, so it is better you to do it by yourself. your question title is not expressing your exact question, for example change it into How to filter a custom dimension in Google Analytics Data API (GA4)

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you have set all the settings correctly including the `Custom Dimensions`, you should do something like:

```
$property_id = 'YOUR_PROPERTY_ID';
$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient([
   'credentials' => 'YOUR_CREDENTIALS' 
]);

$filterExpression = new FilterExpression([
    'filter' => new Filter([
        'field_name'    => 'element_text',
        'string_filter' => new StringFilter([
            'value' => 'widget_open_close',
        ]),
    ]),
]);
```

In case you need to have multiple filters or you need to combine filters:

For example in the following scenario:

- Events with the name `asc_cta_interaction`
  AND
- `element_text` equal to `widget_open_close`
  AND
- (`link_url` equal to `example.com` OR `item_number` equal to `123`)

Then you might use something:

```
 $property_id = 'YOUR_PROPERTY_ID';
    
$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient([
   'credentials' => 'YOUR_CREDENTIALS' 
]);

// Event name filter
$eventNameFilter = new Filter([
    'field_name'    => 'eventName',
    'string_filter' => new StringFilter([
        'value' => 'asc_cta_interaction',
    ]),
]);

// Element text filter
$elementTextFilter = new Filter([
    'field_name'    => 'element_text',
    'string_filter' => new StringFilter([
        'value' => 'widget_open_close',
    ]),
]);

// Link URL filter for OR condition
$linkUrlFilter = new Filter([
    'field_name'    => 'link_url',
    'string_filter' => new StringFilter([
        'value' => 'example.com',
    ]),
]);

// Item number filter for OR condition
$itemNumberFilter = new Filter([
    'field_name'    => 'item_number',
    'string_filter' => new StringFilter([
        'value' => '123',
    ]),
]);

// Combine linkUrlFilter and itemNumberFilter with OR logic
$orFilterExpression = new FilterExpression([
    'or_filters' => new FilterExpressionList([
        'expressions' => [$linkUrlFilter, $itemNumberFilter],
    ]),
]);

// Combine eventNameFilter, elementTextFilter, and orFilterExpression with AND logic
$andFilterExpression = new FilterExpression([
    'and_filters' => new FilterExpressionList([
        'expressions' => [$eventNameFilter, $elementTextFilter, $orFilterExpression],
    ]),
]);
```

I usually code in `JAVA` and there is a similar logic
please have a look at links:
[GA4 Data API - How to set multiple dimensions and metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76906201/ga4-data-api-how-to-set-multiple-dimensions-and-metrics)

[FilterExpression](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/FilterExpression)